# Getting unicode from a urllib request

Tags: python, urllib

I am running the following code trying to find particular information in some HTML.  I am having an encoding/decoding problem, however, that I cannot resolve.

```
import urllib
req = urllib.urlopen('http://securities.stanford.edu/1046/AAI00_01/')
html = req.read()
type(html)
#   <type 'str'>
html.upper().find('HTML')
#   -1
print html[0:20]
#   ??<HTML><HE
html[0:10]
#   '\xff\xfe<\x00H\x00T\x00M\x00'
req.headers['content-type']
#   'text/html'
html = html.encode('utf-8')
#   Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the solution to this problem?  All I need to do is scrape some information from the page using .find and regular expressions.

I am using Mac OSX and running Python 2.6.1 from within Terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to convert from the `str` you have to a `unicode`, you want to use `html.decode`, not `encode`.

**Older, bad advice:** Also, since you seem to have a BOM at the beginning there, you probably 
want to use `'utf_8_sig'` as the encoding, which will strip the BOM on decode.

**New, better advice:** Actually, from seeing all those `\x00`'s in the output along with the BOM, it looks more like the encoding is actually UTF-16, not UTF-8.  So, `html.decode('utf-16')` should be the way to go.